# Single Aplication needed that can cut,split,Flip and add subtitles in large numbers

Tags: video, editing, software-recommendation

I need a single application that can cut, split, flip and add subtitles in large numbers. Currently I use Freemake and Video to video to do this and it takes about 6 to 8 hours for 30 videos.  I'd like to be able to do it without needing multiple applications.

I run Windows 7 with a 3.2ghz AMD processor,Nvidia 460 SE graphics card and 8 gb Ram.

Comment: How long are the videos and how fast is your processor?  6 to 8 hours for 30 videos is not an unreasonable amount of time for this on your hardware if the average length of the videos is more than a couple of minutes each.  Typical encoding times for HD video are two to four times the length of the original video depending on settings.

Comment: Athlon X3 450 at 3.2 GHz with is not very fast,however what I am Trying to do is to use only One application instead of two.

Comment: ah, that was not at all clear from your question.